# Why answers' authors do not up-vote the questions they answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, up-votes, meta

I will admit: I am new here. Still, one thing that has intrigued me is that: why some one who bothers to give an answer to a given question does not up-vote that question?

On the one hand, one might think that a question is worth a reply, but is not necessarily super useful. On the other hand, well, if the question is worth a reply, shouldn't it be consider at least slightly useful?

Answer (score 9):

I think you have pretty much answered this yourself: it's possible to know how to answer a question but at the same time to not think the question as written is well-thought-out or useful for posterity or anything like that.